# A question in matrix norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose

- $A \in {\mathbb C^{n \times n}}$ and $\left\| A \right\| \le \varepsilon $
- $v \in {\mathbb C^n}$ and ${v^*}v = 1$

Is this true that $\left\| {{v^*}Av} \right\| \le \varepsilon $?

Comment: What matrix norm you're using?

Comment: @kermani  - $\left\| A \right\| = \mathop {\max \left\| {Ax} \right\|}\limits_{\left\| x \right\| = 1} $

Comment: What vector norm are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true.  In order to prove that this is the case, we can state that given $\|v\| = 1$:
$$
\|v^*(Av)\| \leq \|v\| \cdot \|Av\| = \|Av\| \leq \|A\| \leq \varepsilon
$$